# How do I place a link directly underneath form field?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a "Forgot my password" link directly underneath the password field. Similarly to how its done on facebook and Linkedin.

When ever i add a p tag, my sign in button gets pushed down, this is not what i want to happen.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: so what do you wan to happen then? Do you want forgotten link to be to the right of the button or above it?

Comment: create jsfiddle for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following below your password `input` and before `.form-group`'s closing `</div>` tag:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
   <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
   <a href="#">Forgot my password</a>
</div>
```

Snippet below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <a href="#">Forgot my password</a>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```